# file type icons using a css rule

Tags: css, history, icons

I'm using [this](http://web-kreation.com/index.php/html-css/add-file-type-icons-next-to-your-links-with-css) approach to display an icon near each link to a file from my web-application.

In order to avoid IE history cache problems I display a link as

```
<a href="path/to/the/file.xls?timestamp=0234562">FileName.xls</a>.
```

In this case the css rule doesn't do his job.

Do you know how can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The selector `a[href$='.xls']` you probably use, applies only if it matches the end of HREF's value. Use `a[href*=.xls]` instead.

Excerpt from [Selectors Level 3](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#attribute-substrings):

> ```
> [att*=val]
> ```
>
> Represents an element with the `att` attribute whose value contains at
>   least one instance of the substring
>   "val". If "val" is the empty string
>   then the selector does not represent
>   anything.

**Edit**

If you have control over the .htaccess file, you may ensure there to avoid cache problems, so you can use your original stylesheet rules. See [Cache-Control Headers using Apache and .htaccess](http://www.askapache.com/htaccess/apache-speed-cache-control.html) for further details.

Comment: But that'd match "file.xls.zip" as well, and I don't think their icons would be the same...

Comment: @Seb In that case you can write `href*=.xls?`.

Comment: @Torok: no, because that would match any string _containing_ ".xls", as the example I gave.

Comment: @Seb: I can't see why. The quotation mark in the end does not allow other patterns. And you can still write `href*=.xls?timestamp=`.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `a[href$='.xls']` matches the end of the `href` attribute of your anchor, but you're appending the timestamp, so the ending of that href is actually the timestamp.

To avoid caching problems you could handle the downloads using a proxy; that is, use a script that triggers the download of files. In PHP it's easily accomplised with readfile() function and sending no-cache headers, for example:

```
<a href="download.php?file=spreadsheet.xls">spreadsheet.xls</a>
```

But since I don't know which programming language you're using, I couldn't say much more.

Comment: i'm using php. can you explain ur approach?

Answer (score 0):

Duncan, I know this has already been answered, but just for your comment, here is a function that should work for you. I think it is almost straight off the PHP manual or some other example(s) somewhere. I have this in a class that handles other things like checking file permissions, uploads, etc. Modify to your needs.

```
public function downloadFile($filename)
{

    // $this->dir is obviously the place where you've got your files
    $filepath = $this->dir . '/' . $filename;
    // make sure file exists
    if(!is_file($filepath))
    {
        header('HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found');
        return 0;
    }
    $fsize=filesize($filepath);

    //set mime-type
    $mimetype = '';
    // mime type is not set, get from server settings
    if (function_exists('finfo_file'))
    {
        $finfo = finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME); // return mime type
        $mimetype = finfo_file($finfo, $filepath);
        finfo_close($finfo);
    }
    if ($mimetype == '')
    {
        $mimetype = "application/force-download";
    }

    // replace some characters so the downloaded filename is cool
    $fname = preg_replace('/\//', '', $filename);
    // set headers
    header("Pragma: public");
    header("Expires: 0");
    header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
    header("Cache-Control: public");
    header("Content-Description: File Transfer");
    header("Content-Type: $mimetype");
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"$fname\"");
    header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
    header("Content-Length: " . $fsize);

    // download
    $file = @fopen($filepath,"rb");
    if ($file)
    {
        while(!feof($file))
        {
            print(fread($file, 1024*8));
            flush();
            if (connection_status()!=0)
            {
                @fclose($file);
                die(); // not so sure if this best... :P
            }
        }
        @fclose($file);
    }
}
```